# Knockout: partial mapping of arrays

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

Have a look at [this small example](http://jsfiddle.net/8sGuY/2/).

```
<select data-bind="options: Days, optionsText: 'title'"></select>
<input type="button" value="update" data-bind="click: update" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var Days = {'Days': [{"id":1,"title":"Monday"},{"id":2,"title":"Tuesday"},{"id":3,"title":"Wensday"}]};

var DaysUpdate = {'Days': [{"id":3,"title":"Wednesday"},{"id":4,"title":"Thursday"},{"id":5,"title":"Friday"}]};

var mapping = {    
    'Days': {        
        key: function(data) {            
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);        
        }    
}}

var viewModel = {
    Days: ko.observableArray(),
    update: function() {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(DaysUpdate, mapping, viewModel);
    }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(Days, mapping, viewModel);


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

In this example data is mapped partially. First from Days object, then (by clicking update button) from DaysUpdate object. The the second update removes "Monday" and "Tuesday" objects from the array. How do I make those stay?

PS. Thanks to Mark Robinson for better structured example.

Comment: This fiddle demonstrates your problem. Maybe another SO user can use it to provide a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/PfFf9/1/

Comment: Great! Thanks for the fiddle. I will reference it in the question.

Comment: @Dziamid - i just corrected a small typo in your code, there was a space after the 'Days' mapping which caused the key not to be used. It doesn't affect my answer however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common question re the mapping plugin. Currently there is no way to do this with the plugin itself. It's been a bugging me for a while. The plugin assumes that the array you gave it is the new contents of the array so removes the other items.

The only solution I know of at present is to loop through the collection and manually map each element.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/5878E/

One of these days I'll get around to trying to come up with a proper solution and send a pull request to the mapping plugin guys.

Hope this helps.